# How to create an array in javascript with element at specific position only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to create an array in Javascript with only one (or more) given element at a given position.

See the following snippet:

```js
params = [];

params[5] = "my value"
params[14] = "my other value";

console.log(params);
```

All the elements that I don't initialize are (as expected) undefined. Can I delete these undefined elements, before or after the array is created?

Also, what happens if I set the array as POST data for a JQuery $.ajax() call?

Comment: Why don't you use an object instead of an array?

Comment: What do you mean by "delete these undefined elements"?  If you don't want empty array elements, why are you skipping them in the first place?  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just use an object then?

```
params = {};

params[5] = "my value"
params[14] = "my other value";

console.log(params);
```

Comment: You're right, it worked. Never thought of using objects like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Associative Arrays as also

```
  var person = [];
person[0] = "John";
person[10] = "Doe";
person[20] = 46;

    console.log(person);

array=(
'key1'=>''value1,
'key2'=>''value2
);

if you want to use in loop

result=array()
for(i=10;i<5;i++){

array1=(
'key1'=>''value1,
'key2'=>''value2
);
result=array1;
}

console.log(result)
```